# Cancelling ulimit bounds

Tags: c++, linux, docker, ulimit, setrlimit

I am writing isolated sandbox for untrusted code so I am looking for safe way to isolate code execution. Also I need a way to collect code stats (memory usage, cpu usage, etc.)

I have tried Docker but Stats API can stream only with a second period and some code (especially written in C or C++) runs 1000+ times faster.

I have asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722875/limiting-memory-usage-of-spawned-process) about `setrlimit` but people in comments written that user can cancel limits (may be there is a way to prevent user from doing this?)

Also I have heard about `ulimit`. Is that way safe enough and can't be overwritten by user?

Comment: A user process can always lower a ulimit-controlled resource. ulimit-controlled resources cannot be increased, except by root (more or less).

Comment: You set limits for a _process_ with `setrlimit()` (the shell `ulimit` command really calls `setrlimit()` when interpreted).  Then all future descendant processes (though `fork()`/`clone()`) will inherit those limits, and the limits persist across system calls that change the program image (`execve()`) and credentials (`setuid()`, `setgid()`, `setgroups()` etc.).

Comment: @Paulo1205 as described in link process can increase limits by calling `setrlimit` again

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but how do I call ulimit on another user? If I execute it as this user can he cancel it? Also I tried to set ulimit -u 1 and wrote sleep 20 & several times but it had no effect

Comment: @NikitaLapkov, there are two kinds of limits: soft and hard.  Soft limits can be freely changed (down or up) by any user at any time, as long as they don't exceed the corresponding hard limits.  Hard limits can only be lowered, and never again increased (unless the user trying to perform the increase is root).

Comment: To collect data check `perf`, Don't know about Docker Stats API, but it probably "reports" data once per second, but collects data much faster.

Comment: @Paulo1205 thank you very much! Can you provide source (man page or something like this) to proof your statement? And please make an answer from your comment so I could mark it as solution

Comment: @xvan Thank you! I have failed to install on docker (perf not found for kernel 4.1.19) but I think it is what I was looking for!

Comment: @NikitaLapkov, `man setrlimit`?